# Tomcat ignores manuall set Keep-Alive Header

Tags: java, tomcat, header, keep-alive

we had our operating system and tomcat updated. After a few days we noticed that the keep-alive headers were no longer being forwarded.

The class is HttpServlet and in the doPost Method the headers get set can be seen as follows:

```
response.setStatus(200);
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
response.setHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout = 20000 max = 100");
```

Is there a setting at Tomcat which prohibits the applications from setting the values or does someone have an idea what might be the cause?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such setting. Are you sure you are not using HTTP2? HTTP2 does not use this header.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked the tomcat server.xml and the protocol ist HTTP1.1. 
Or did you mean something else?